# LWC: Unable to debug platformResourceLoader error

Tags: lightning-web-components, platformresourceloader

I am trying to load several js files in my LWC. But 3 out of the 4 files are failing to load and I can't figure out why.

Here's my code:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { loadStyle, loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import MY_RESOURCES from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/my_resources';

export default class MyWidgetDs extends LightningElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        Promise.all([
            loadScript(this, MY_RESOURCES + '/some_folder/myFirstFile.js').catch(error => {
                console.log('p1 failed');
                console.log(error);
            }),
            loadScript(this, MY_RESOURCES + '/some_folder/mySecondFile.js').catch(error => {
                  console.log('p2 failed');
                  console.log(error);
              }),
            loadScript(this, MY_RESOURCES + '/some_folder/myThirdFile.js').catch(error => {
                   console.log('p3 failed');
                   console.log(error);
               }),
            loadScript(this, MY_RESOURCES + '/some_folder/myFourthFile.js').catch(error => {
                   console.log('p4 failed');
                   console.log(error);
               }),
        ]).then(value => {
            console.log('all loading of resources is complete');
            console.log(value);
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log('ERROR IS ' );
            console.log(error);
            console.log(error.message);
        })
    }
}
```

What I get in the console is this:

[image: lwc_loading_of_resources_promise_failure]

So it appears to me that `p2` is loading correctly but how do I see what the issue is with the loading of the other 3 promises?

Also am I not supposed to see `value` in the `then.` portion? All of the values come as `undefined` again. Shouldn't `p2` have a value?

Comment: Why are you using individual catch blocks for each loadResource? wont promise all handle it?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal I was trying to see if all of the files were failing or if any were managing to load.